# Update statement containing aggregate not working in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, aggregate

I am hoping someone can help my syntax here. 
I have two tables `ansicache..encounters` and `ansicache..x_refclaim_Table`

The `encounters` table has an `encounter` column that matches the `patacctnumber` column in the `x_refclaim_table`.

However, sometimes the `patacctnumber` can show up twice in the `x_refclaim_table` with different service dates (column `iar_servicedate`).

I am trying to update the `encounters` table, `admitted` column to the maximum value of the `iar_servicedate` where the `encounter` in `encounters` table = `patacctnumber` in `x_refclaim` table

```
 update ansicache..ENCOUNTERS 
       set ADMITTED=max(IAR_ServiceDate) 
 from
     (
       ansicache..ENCOUNTERS e (nolock) 
          join 
       ansicache..x_refClaim_table x (nolock)
          on e.ENCOUNTER=x.PatAcctNumber
      )
```

It keeps failing though:

> Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

I tried doing some other stuff like declaring an ID but couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a correlated sub query

```
UPDATE e
SET    ADMITTED = (SELECT max(IAR_ServiceDate)
                   FROM   ansicache..x_refClaim_table x
                   WHERE  e.ENCOUNTER = x.PatAcctNumber)
FROM   ansicache..ENCOUNTERS e
```

Answer (score 4):

you can preaggreagate your data before update.

```
update ansicache..ENCOUNTERS set
    ADMITTED = x.IAR_ServiceDate
from ansicache..ENCOUNTERS as e
    inner join (
        select
            x.PatAcctNumber, max(x.IAR_ServiceDate) as IAR_ServiceDate
        from ansicache..x_refClaim_table as x
        group by x.PatAcctNumber
    ) as x on x.PatAcctNumber = e.ENCOUNTER
```

It's usually more preferred method for me than subquery, because you can use `max(...)` several times if you need it, or you can use other aggregates additionally, so it's easier to maintain this query in the future:

```
update ansicache..ENCOUNTERS set
    ADMITTED = x.IAR_ServiceDate,
    ADMITTED2 = dateadd(dd, 5, x.IAR_ServiceDate2)
from ansicache..ENCOUNTERS as e
    inner join (
        select
            x.PatAcctNumber,
            max(x.IAR_ServiceDate) as IAR_ServiceDate,
            min(x.IAR_ServiceDate) as IAR_ServiceDate2
        from ansicache..x_refClaim_table as x
        group by x.PatAcctNumber
    ) as x on x.PatAcctNumber = e.ENCOUNTER
```

Another way to do this is to put `max` into `apply`:

```
update ansicache..ENCOUNTERS set
    ADMITTED = x.IAR_ServiceDate,
    ADMITTED2 = dateadd(dd, 5, x.IAR_ServiceDate2)
from ansicache..ENCOUNTERS as e
    cross apply (
        select
            max(x.IAR_ServiceDate) as IAR_ServiceDate,
            min(x.IAR_ServiceDate) as IAR_ServiceDate2
        from ansicache..x_refClaim_table as x
        where x.PatAcctNumber = e.ENCOUNTER
    ) as x
```