# SQL Server: insert into one table the maximum value from another where key values are the same

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a control table of plots and a weather table. They are both linked by a GeographicalPlotID field.

I'd like to insert into each plot's WeatherDataPulled field the latest value found in the weather table for that plot.

I have this query, which is not working-the multi-part identifier can't be bound. I've tried inner joins, with no luck.

```
insert into 
ControlTable(WeatherDataPulled)
select
max(Time) 
from WeatherData
where (ControlTable.PlotID = WeatherData.PlotID
and ControlTable.PlotID is not null)
```

The join looked like this:

```
inner join
WeatherData
on 
ControlTable.PlotID = WeatherData.PlotID
```

Any idea on what I need to do to get this working?

Comment: What have you tried with `JOIN`? Add that sql query too. Do you really want to insert or update an existing row?

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably need an update statement and not an insert statement.
Try this instead:

```
UPDATE ControlTable
SET WeatherDataPulled = MAX([TIME])
FROM ControlTable
INNER JOIN WeatherData ON ControlTable.PlotID = WeatherData.PlotID
```

Comment: Do you mean, rather, this:
SET WeatherDataPulled = MAX([TIME])
FROM WeatherData
?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the approach suggested by Zorah would lead to an error, since an aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

See here: [Update statement containing aggregate not working in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034029/update-statement-containing-aggregate-not-working-in-sql-server)

Your update statement (as written in your answer below) includes a subquery which works fine, and hence is the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As Zohar pointed out, I was stupidly using insert instead of update.

Got it working with this:

`update
ControlTable
set WeatherDataPulled=
(select max(Time) 
from 
WeatherData
where
ControlTable.PlotID = WeatherData.PlotID)`